# Spent vs Spending

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, passive-voice, past-participles, present-participles

What is the difference between,

> The three pie charts below show the changes in annual spent by a particular school in 1981, 1991 and 2001.

> The three pie charts below show the changes in annual spending by a particular school in 1981, 1991 and 2001.

1. Is *spent* from the first one past participle?
2. Is *spending* from the second one present participle?

Why don't we use *spent* because "the changes(money) were spent by a particular school"?

Comment: The first sentence is bad grammar. "Annual" is an adjective that should modify a following noun, but "spent" is a past verb form.

Comment: I thought annual is a noun. Your comment is helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is historic data about *money that has been spent*. Money is a noun, so anything that substitutes for this is likely to also be a noun.

In this kind of context, "spending" is a *gerund* - a verb used as a noun. It means either the money spent in a specific period, or the process/practice of spending money. "Spent" is not suitable for this context, as it is the wrong verb form to be used as a gerund. You could say "money spent" (eg "changes in money spent annually")

You may sometimes see the word 'spend' used in this context (eg "changes in annual spend") which may seem equally ungrammatical, but is accounting terminology.